# How to get string between 2 different quotes

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I trying to get device address from `scanimage -L` which return

```
device `canon_dr:libusb:003:004' is a CANON DR-C125 scanner
```

I came up with this

```bash
grep -Po '`\K[^']+'
```

but dont understend how to properly isolate special symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```bash
grep -Po "\`\\K[^']+"
```

Note that inside the double quoted string literal, the backtick and backslash need escaping.

You can also use `awk` here:

```bash
awk -F"[\`']" '{print $2}'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/a89pz3):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='device `canon_dr:libusb:003:004'"'"' is a CANON DR-C125 scanner'
grep -Po "\`\\K[^']+" <<< "$s"
# => canon_dr:libusb:003:004
awk -F"[\`']" '{print $2}' <<< "$s"
# => canon_dr:libusb:003:004
```